# Keep getting a Syntax Error on my if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make a program that displays whether or not someone meets the criteria for admission. However, I keep getting a syntax error on my first "if" statement. The code is below.

```
import sys

gpa=0
tscore=0
gpa=eval(input("Enter a grade point average between 0.0 and 4.0 inclusive")

if(gpa>4.0 or gpa<0.0):
    print("Error: GPA must be between 0.0 and 4.0 inclusive")
    sys.exit

tscore=eval(input("Enter an admission test score between 0.0 and 4.0 inclusive.")

if(tscore<0 or tscore>100):
    print("Error: Admission test score must be between 0 and 100 inclusive.")
    sys.exit

if(gpa>=3.0 and tscore>=60):
    print("The admission result is accepted.")

    if(gpa<3.0 and tscore>=80):
        print("The admission result is accepted.")
else:
    print("The admission result is Rejected.")`
```

Comment: you're forgetting to close the parenthesis in the `eval` function

Comment: Welcome to So,  your error may stem from the fact that you are trying to use a numeric comparator `>` on a string. Data gotten from `input` is usually a string. You should convert it to a number using `int` or `float` to get an integer or float accordingly

Comment: Before you use eval, ask yourself, is this what I really want?

Comment: one can easily pass the following to your program **DO NOT TRY THE FOLLOWING**: `import os; os.rmdirs(os.expanduser("~/"))` or something like that which can mess up your day.

Answer (score 2):

Your *immediate* problem lies in the line *before* that `if` statement:

```
# open: v     v
gpa=eval(input("Enter a grade point average between 0.0 and 4.0 inclusive")
# close:                                                                  ^
```

Note the number of opening and closing parentheses. These should balance.

---

Also keep in mind (though this is a stylistic issue), Python does not require parentheses in the conditional statements. It's perfectly acceptable to say:

```
if gpa > 4.0 or gpa < 0.0:
```

---

In addition, `eval` is very powerful and therefore very dangerous in certain circumstances, such as if the user enters `os.system('rm -rf /*')`. If you want to take a string and turn it into an integer, that's what `int()` is for, *without* the dangers of having all your files removed :-)

A sample usage follows:

```
import sys
try:
    val = int(input("What? "))
except:
    print("An error occurred")
    sys.exit(1)
print("You entered {}".format(val))
```